# How To Solve $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\bar z}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\bar z}{z}$

I solved this by breaking $z$ into its component

$$z=x+iy$$
and
$$\bar z = x - iy$$

And I got 1 after checking the limit as x approaches 0 and y approaching 0 thereafter.

I also got 1 trying it the other way i.e $y\to 0, x\to 0$

So is the answer 1? Or was my approach faulty?

Comment: Consider what happens when you approach $0$ on the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis separately.

Comment: conclusion : $\frac{z}{\overline{z}}$ is real continuous but not complex continuous at $z=0$

Comment: Note that $$\frac{\bar z}{z}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-i\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$$Neither the real nor imaginary part of the right-hand side has a limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$.  So, the limit fails to exist.

Answer (score 3):

If we approach along the positive real axis,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x}=1$$

but if we approach along the positive imaginary axis,
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-iy}{iy}=-1.$$

Comment: And you can get any complex number on the unit circle, by approaching along a ray whose angle is half the argument of that number.

Comment: Yes, it is all much easier if you represent $z$ in polar coordinates - if $z=re^{i\theta}$ then $\overline{z}=re^{-i\theta}$ and $$\frac{\overline z}{z} = e^{-2i\theta}$$ which is constant as $r\to 0$ if $\theta$ is fixed.